# How to set controller date in test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage, date-picker

how to set a date in the test class, Thanks in advance.

visual force page:

```
<apex:page controller=IntegrationController" docType="html-5.0">
       <apex:outputPanel >
          <div style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">
              select Date: <apex:input type="date" value="{!dt}"/>
          </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:commandButton value="Get Data" action="{!getData}" />
```

</apex:page>

**controller**:

```
    public class IntegrationController{
   public Date dt {get;set;}
    public void getData(){            
    system.debug('in controller ---> '+dt); 
    String dat = dt.year() + '/' + dt.month() + '/' + dt.day();}
```

test class:

```
    @isTest
public class IntegrationController_Test {
static testmethod void test1(){
  Date  testDate =Date.newInstance(2020, 10, 28);        
    system.debug('in test class: '+testDate );
  Test.startTest();         
          IntegrationController Data = new IntegrationController();
           Data.getData();
     Test.stopTest();
```

}

After running the test class I am getting a null value in controller date. Please help me with this issue.

```
14:16:47:001 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|in test class: 2020-10-28 00:00:00
14:16:47:065 USER_DEBUG [22]|DEBUG|in controller ---> null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the same way you set a variable for any other class. Dot notation.

```
IntegrationController myController = new IntegrationController();
// If the property is public or has a public setter, you can use dot notation 
//   like normal
myController.dt = Date.today();

Test.startTest();
myController.getData();
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: you're awesome. Thank you so much for your help. you made my day great !!!